# Invalid arguments in Pear\Downloader.php while installing Trader.php

Tags: php

Installing Trader, I am encountering the following errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR\PackageFile\v2\Validator.php on line 870

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\PackageFile\v2\Validator.php on line 870
332 source files, building

WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix .exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP trader.dsp does not exist.
```

I initially encountered an error when installing Trader, and this was my fix:

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in PEAR\PackageFile\v2\Validator.php on line 1933
```

... which is apparently a bug in php7.3. So I changed that to "continue 2", and my trader install progressed to another error:

Answer (score 0):

Code of required library might not be fully compatible with PHP7.3.

I would suggest looking at your composer file to see if there are strict requirements for php7.3 and then explicitely call composer with php7.2 instead : `php7.2 $(which composer) install`.

Just be aware that composer will check extensions dependencies based on your php7.2 installation. Eventually pass the --ignore-platform-reqs flag to suppress the warnings.
Worked for me.